# Why does this loop in python runs progressively slower?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this code, there is a 4-D array of 13x13 images. I would like to save each 13x13 image using *matplotlib.pyplot*. Here for debugging purposes, I limit the outer loop to 1.

```
#fts is a numpy array of shape (4000,100,13,13)
no_images = 4000
for m in [1]:  
    for i in range(no_images):
        print i,
        fm = fts[i][m]
        if fm.min() != fm.max():
            fm -= fm.min()
            fm /= fm.max()  #scale to [0,1]
        else:
            print 'unscaled'
        plt.imshow(fmap)
        plt.savefig('m'+str(m)+'_i'+str(i)+'.png')
```

Saving 4000 images took more than 20 hours. Why is it this slow?
If I limit the inner loop to the first 100 images, it takes about 1 minute. So the whole thing should be completed in 40 minutes, not over 20 hours! And I notice it seems to run progressively slower.

Comment: How is the memory consumption developing? You do imshow(fmap) for all your images.

Comment: try calling `plt.close()` below savefig to clean up resources each time you iterate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you experience here is a memory leak: you keep creating instances of `AxesImage` objects (by repetitively calling `plt.imshow`) to the moment they can't fit into RAM; and then the whole thing begins swapping to disk, which is *incredibly* slow. To avoid memory leaks, you can either destroy `AxesImage` instance when you don't need it:

```
...
image = plt.imshow(fmap)
plt.savefig('m'+str(m)+'_i'+str(i)+'.png')
del(image)
```

Or, alternatively, you can create only one `AxesImage`, and then just change the data in it:

```
...
image = None
for m in [1]:  
    for i in range(no_images):
        ...
        if image is None:
             image = plt.imshow(fmap)
        else:
             image.set_data(fmap)
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, the second method made it faster (about 20 seconds for 100 images) ! It doesn't seem to be a memory thing though, cause the RAM never became full. 4000 images completed while I type this!

Comment: Ok, so I see. You're allocating memory, and this is also a slow process, especially in Python. That's also the reason of why the first method didn't work out for you.

Comment: For me, the first solution didn't work but the second one did.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and I tried the above solutions but my dataset is too big for my ram it just collapses after running 20000 images and then I got the answer both `plt.close()` and `del image` are not working because they are not clearing total data which is stored they the just adding strain to ram to clear total plt data we need to use `plt.figure().clear()`, `plt.close()`, `plt.cla()`, `plt.clf()`

This might work for you

```
#fts is a numpy array of shape (4000,100,13,13)
no_images = 4000
for m in [1]:  
    for i in range(no_images):
        print i,
        fm = fts[i][m]
        if fm.min() != fm.max():
            fm -= fm.min()
            fm /= fm.max()  #scale to [0,1]
        else:
            print 'unscaled'
        plt.imshow(fmap)
        plt.savefig('m'+str(m)+'_i'+str(i)+'.png')
        plt.figure().clear()
        plt.close()
        plt.cla()
        plt.clf()
```